# Windows command to change directory to the output of a text file

Tags: windows, cmd

I have this long path of the temporary folder of a project:
c:\\Users\\user\\source\\repos\\src\\etc\\even\\longer

I stored the string of text of the path in the file "path.txt" for the time being.

I would like to change directory from the windows command line like I would in Bash

```
$ cd `cat path.txt`
```

I tried with `cd < type path.txt` but I got.

> The system cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score 2):

You try to redirect the contents of a file named `type` to the `cd` command. The correct syntax would be `cd < path.txt` or `type path.txt | cd` - if `cd` would take input from STDIN, which it does not.

You have to read the content of `path.txt` to a variable and use `cd` with that variable.

There are two methods to read from a file: `set /p` and a `for /f` loop.

**A**

```
<path.txt set /p folder=
cd /d "%folder%"
```

or **B**

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("path.txt") do set folder=%%a
cd /d "%folder%"
```

or (directly processing) **C**

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("path.txt") do cd /d "%%a"
```

(All methods assuming there is just one line in the file - method A reads the first line only, method B reads all (non-empty) lines, keeping the last one in the variable and method C would `cd` in every folder listed in the file.)

Comment: The method A worked as expected. I got '%%a was unexpected at this time.' for the other two. Thank you.

Comment: use `%%a` in batch files, and `%a` directly on the command line.

Comment: understood, thank you